# c++ amp: compound type, for loop, declaration on GPU

Tags: c++, c++-amp

I'm working on a simulation code with c++ amp. I have the following questions and couldn't find a clear for them. Hope somebody would help. Actually, they are related to each other.

I wrote some lines like this and it works, I've tested the results but I need somebody to point out why it's right or wrong.

```
class sample
{
    double x;
    double y;
    bool good;
};

vector<sample> A;

//push_back some values for A

double M[3];

array_view<sample,1> ar(A.size(),A);
array_view<double,1> m(3,M);

double t = 1;


parallel_for_each(ar.extent, [=](index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
{
    double a, b; // Q1
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)  //Q2
    {
        a += m[i]*ar[idx].x;
        b += m[i]*ar[idx].y;
    }

    ar[idx].x = a;
    ar[idx].y = b;

    if ( (a+b) > 1 ) 
        ar[idx].good = 0; //Q3
});

ar.synchronize();
```

**Q1** Can we make declaration inside parallel_for_each as shown in this example? These variables have a GPU scope? If so, on GPU, are these variables stored in a common memory space or for each core/thread in GPU, it has their own local memory, so that all calculation will not affect each other? Can we even decalare an array or vector for temp use?

**Q2** using 'for' loop inside parallel_for_each is recommended? any comments on this?

**Q3** using 'if' inside parallel_for_each, especially as shown here, as member of some class is recommended? If there're some drawbacks, I'll make the check outside the parralel_for_each.

Basically this example shows what I want to do: I want to built a class, which would generate a vector (lots of) of object, they will updated by a matrix. I want to use c++ amp to accelerate the calculation.

I might have include too many questions here, please comment on any of them. Thanks ahead.

Comment: It's really confusing that you have `a` as an `array_view` in the outer scope, and re-declared as a `double` in the parallel_for scope.

Comment: Thanks, @acraig5075. Edited. Do you have any remarks on the declaration in side the parallel_for_each body? In fact, I want to declare an array inside the parallel_for_each, because in my calculation, the matrix will be different for each element of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1:** `a` and `b` are declared in thread scope. Each thread has its own copy. As with all C++ variables you should initialize them. Yes, you can declare an array here but be careful allocating large amounts of per-thread data. GPUs have small amounts of per-thread memory. This may limit the number of threads the GPU is able to to execute currently leading to low occupancy and reduced performance.

**Q2:** This `for` loop is OK-ish because it runs exactly the same on each thread. Remember a thread implies branching and this can lead to warp divergence if different threads in the warp follow different branches. You might want to manually unroll this loop, or the compiler might do it for you.

**Q3:** In general you should avoid branching within `parallel_for_each` because this can result in warp divergence. The loop here is pretty bad because the `( (a+b) > 1 )` condition  will have threads that evaluate true and false on each warp.

The other thing you should really consider is avoiding using an array of structs, `array_view<sample,1>` as it leads to poor memory access patterns. You would be better off using separate arrays to store `x`, `y` and `good`. This will allow the GPU to coalesce memory loads.

Yes, a class/struct is easier to use but in general will impact perf. Depending on how large your codebase is moving from an array of structs (AoS) to a struct of arrays (SoA) later may be painful. Unrolling the AoS into an SoA at runtime for use on the GPU is probably worth avoiding too as it requires a lot of memory copies, which in turn are a big perf hit. AoS works fine, just be aware of the likely performance inpact and long term implications to a (larger) codebase.

Because your loop is a fixed size and so small you may want to unroll it. If the values in `M` are constant then you should probably not bother with storing them in a global array at all and simply hard code them. You may also be able to replace the `if` conditional with a function that gives the same result.

Example below. I've not tested the performance of this. It may be faster, you should benchmark it as these are just suggestions.

```
#include <amp_math.h>

struct sample
{
    double x;
    double y;
    bool good;
public:
    sample(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y), good(true) { }
};

main()
{
    std::array<sample, 2> A = { sample(0.0000001, 0.0), sample(1.0, 1.0) };
    double M[3] = { 1.0, 1.5, 2.0 };

    array_view<sample, 1> ar(A.size(), A);
    array_view<double, 1> m(3, M);

    double t = 1;

    parallel_for_each(ar.extent, [=](concurrency::index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
    {
        ar[idx].x = m[0] * ar[idx].x + m[1] * ar[idx].x + m[2] * ar[idx].x;
        ar[idx].y = m[0] * ar[idx].y + m[1] * ar[idx].y + m[2] * ar[idx].y;

        // WARNING: Single precision!
        ar[idx].good = !concurrency::fast_math::signbit(ar[idx].x + ar[idx].y - 1.0);
    });

    ar.synchronize();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and suggestions. Especially Q1, the GPU memory pattern really confused me a lot. I read your book (C++ AMP) and learned that an array of class is less effective. But a class can hold different types of data together so it's way simpler to use. I will unroll them to different vectors if the performance turns out unacceptable. I understand the branching like if will drag the performance, but I really want to mark some items and remove them later from the vector. Any advices or examples on this?